# What resources will help me understand the data model for QC 10.0 in order to write my SQL queries?

Tags: quality-center, qtp, sql

I am a fresher in Quality Center 10.0 HP software testing tool.

As per my understanding in order to generate reports from QC and to troubleshoot the scenarios, we need to write SQL queries in the QC back end database. In my case it is SQL db.

I downloaded the database reference help file but I could not understand from where I can start.

It just gave the table name and its information.

For a starter like me are there any online tutorials or helpful websites,hands on exercises,scenario's where I can better understand how to write queries for the QC data model? I am very confident about the SQL coding itself, what I want to know is how to query on the QC database tables based on the scenarios that occur in QC tool.

Please suggest.

Thanks, 
Srihari

Comment: Hi After some through search i found this article http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-retrieve-requirement-test-case.html please share your stuff or tutorial sites of this kind, which is very easy to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are looking for help to learn SQL, for help understanding QC's data model, or a bit of both - could you tell us a little bit more, so that people can make their answers more specific for you?

Comment: Hi testerab, I am very confident about the SQL coding I only want to know how can I write these SQL queries for the QC data model.I want to know how to query on the QC database tables based on the scenarios that occur in QC tool.

Comment: Okay thanks srihari - that's a lot more useful. Now that I know you're confident in SQL generally, I know that I don't need to add general SQL tips here. I don't use QC myself any more, so I can't help you with understanding its data model, but I've added the extra information you gave us to the title and the question body, to help attract people who might be able to help you. (Most people don't click on all questions, so it's really worth working on making the title as informative and accurate as possible).

Comment: Yes testerab I understood , will correct the mistake next time,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Srihari... I'm also relatively new to QC. With regard to querying the QC DB, mostly I retrieve BUG data, and learned primarily through trial and error in the Dashboard module. Initially, I didn't know which columns to include so I just did a query to select * from BUG where bg_bug_id = <some bug ID I had logged>

Essentially, my base query on BUG is written below. And I just revise from there.

```
SELECT
  BUG.BG_BUG_ID,
  RELEASES.REL_NAME as "Detected in Release",
  RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_NAME as "Detected in Cycle",
  BUG.BG_DETECTED_BY as "Submitted By",
  BUG.BG_SUMMARY as Summary,
  BUG.BG_DESCRIPTION as Description,
  BUG.BG_STATUS as State
  -- plus other BUG details
FROM BUG
  LEFT JOIN RELEASES
   ON BUG.BG_DETECTED_IN_REL = RELEASES.REL_ID
  LEFT JOIN RELEASE_CYCLES
   ON BUG.BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC = RELEASE_CYCLES.RCYC_ID
-- WHERE clause
-- ORDER BY 1
```

'hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Keis, Thank you very much for your advice and support,So you also started like me :), Lets get some more details from this forum's members who might know more on this from their experience.

Answer (score 0):

If ( and it's an 'if' as your question is not clear ) you want to learn SQL there is the recent 'Learn SQL The Hard Way' at http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/

I have this on my list of things to try out so I can refresh my SQL knowledge